# Does UILocalNotification automatically get destroyed after invocation?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uilocalnotification

I am wondering if UILocalNotification gets destroyed once it's invoked (the user receives the notification), or if it just stays in the memory until the total number of notifications reaches 64 and gets flushed away by the newly scheduled ones.

For example, if I scheduled 10 UILocalNotifications to go off after 10 minutes, what happens if I run

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *notifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: It's almost certainly removed from the collection once triggered, but why not take the ten minutes you cite to try it, yourself?

Comment: @Justin Only in certain situations will the notification object be discarded - when the UILocalNotification only badges an icon. In other cases when an alert is presented the UILocalNotification lives on and can pass data into the delegate method with options so that you can execute further code such as opening up a specific message thread in a messaging application for example. Read the passage I quoted in my answer retrieved from the apple docs to get your answers Vlad.

Comment: @Pavan I stand by my claim that they're removed from the collection once triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A passage from the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reads

*An application can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest*

**What happens to the UILocalNotification when invoked:**

When the system delivers a local notification, `several things can happen`, depending on the application state and the type of notification... ...In the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method `the application delegate can obtain the UILocalNotification object from the passed-in options dictionary by using the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` key.`

The delegate `can inspect the properties of the notification` and, `if the notification includes custom data in its userInfo dictionary, it can access that data and process it accordingly`. On the other hand, `if the local notification only badges the application icon`, and the user in response launches the application, the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is invoked, `but no UILocalNotification object is included` in the options dictionary.

Comment: This doesn't say what happens to the notifications once they're fired. It only talks about what happens after the 65th schedule

Comment: @Vlad funnily enough, I was editing my answer to include that exact infrmation during which you commented :D hehe

Comment: thanks for helping, but what i meant by "What happens after it fires" was does that UILocalNotification object get removed from memory forever, or if it sticks around (but never get fired again obviously since it's been already fired), until the total number of UILocalNotifications (expired or not expired) exceeds 64 and the next one that comes into the queue pushes the oldest one and so forth

Comment: @Vlad Yes, there is no need for it to keep the UILocalNotification object after the delegate method is called. Therefor, if you wanted to save it for whatever reason, you've got to save it in your own UILocalNotification object until the memory management sees it fit for removal or until you release the object. Its like a UIViewController that gets popped back to the mainViewController; what happens to it? It is removed from memory.

Comment: @Vlad again depending on the type of UILocalNotification, clearly stated in the apple docs to which they like to say, it gets `discarded` otherwise it gets passed into the delegate method until the garbage collector sees it fit to discard the object after which it will release/discard the notification object.

Comment: ok, so since it's garbage collection based, theoretically it is possible that [app scheduledLocalNotifications] will return expired notifications, right?

Comment: @Vlad as far as im aware, [app scheduledLocalNotifications]; will return an array of notifications that have yet to be fired. I believe expired notifications will not be shown in the array at all and would have been discarded of especially if those notifications have an invalid date.

Comment: While the answer was intuited correctly, there is no garbage collector on iOS. Do not make decisions based on the belief that there is.

Comment: Oh right, hey @Justin could you perhaps tell me what Apple means when they say they discard the UILocalNotification?

Comment: They mean exactly that. They make no attempt to keep the notification around. You cannot rely on it to exist without intervening. Under the hood, they're almost certainly removing it from some system collection of notifications to be fired. For a better understanding of memory management on iOS and why removing an object from a collection might release it, read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Ok then so instead I should have kept it concise to, the UILocalNotifcation gets discarded instead of saying probably by the garbage collector, since there is no garbage collector. Got it